# Symbolizing vector layer in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology

`"symbols()"` is no longer available in QGIS 3.0 and replaced by `"QgsRenderContext& context"` method, but I do not find the correct way to write this instruction.

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

lyr=iface.activeLayer()
symbols = lyr.renderer().symbols()
sym = symbols[0]
sym.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,0,0))

lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change

```
symbols=lyr.renderer().symbols()
```

to

```
symbols = lyr.renderer().symbols(QgsRenderContext())
```

and everything will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, “symbols()” is no longer available in qgis3.0 and replaced by “QgsRenderContext& context” method, but I do not find the correct way to write this instruction.
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
lyr=iface.activeLayer()
symbols = lyr.renderer().symbols()
sym = symbols[0]
sym.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,0,0))
lyr.triggerRepaint()

Comment: @ennine I have edited my answer. Hope this answers your edited question.